# Problema con Highcharts al momento de graficar

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Trato de hacer esta gráfica https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail, yo creo el JSON con datos de mi BD, mi problema es que no me grafica desde la primera hora del día `1583478000000 => 2020-03-06 01:00` sino que me grafica desde el `2020-03-06 07:00`, apenas estoy conociendo esta librería de gráficas, alguna idea de que pudiera ser?

```
[
    [
        1583478000000,
        0
    ],
    [
        1583481600000,
        0.000123358
    ],
    [
        1583485200000,
        0.000100023
    ],
    [
        1583488800000,
        0.00000667
    ],
    [
        1583492400000,
        0.000346758
    ],
    [
        1583496000000,
        0.000326751
    ],
    [
        1583499600000,
        0.001083631
    ],
    [
        1583503200000,
        0.01746138
    ],
    [
        1583506800000,
        0.07145513
    ],
    [
        1583510400000,
        0.1640194
    ],
    [
        1583514000000,
        0.3075443
    ],
    [
        1583517600000,
        0.527993
    ],
    [
        1583521200000,
        1.580313
    ],
    [
        1583524800000,
        1.868847
    ],
    [
        1583528400000,
        0.5814131
    ],
    [
        1583532000000,
        0.5110745
    ],
    [
        1583535600000,
        0.2855772
    ],
    [
        1583539200000,
        0.1762918
    ],
    [
        1583542800000,
        0.03129992
    ],
    [
        1583546400000,
        0.001756899
    ],
    [
        1583550000000,
        0.001330334
    ],
    [
        1583553600000,
        0.000630177
    ],
    [
        1583557200000,
        0.0000367
    ],
    [
        1583560800000,
        0
    ],
    [
        1583564400000,
        0.0000367
    ],
    [
        1583568000000,
        0
    ],
    [
        1583571600000,
        0.000873724
    ],
    [
        1583575200000,
        0.001123729
    ],
    [
        1583578800000,
        0.000890336
    ],
    [
        1583582400000,
        0.000243418
    ],
    [
        1583586000000,
        0.001463911
    ],
    [
        1583589600000,
        0.180205
    ],
    [
        1583593200000,
        0.3074751
    ],
    [
        1583596800000,
        1.5091
    ],
    [
        1583600400000,
        1.831689
    ],
    [
        1583604000000,
        2.77784
    ],
    [
        1583607600000,
        2.744292
    ],
    [
        1583611200000,
        1.867965
    ],
    [
        1583614800000,
        0.4991449
    ],
    [
        1583618400000,
        0.4433156
    ],
    [
        1583622000000,
        0.3356347
    ],
    [
        1583625600000,
        0.1854026
    ],
    [
        1583629200000,
        0.05021589
    ],
    [
        1583632800000,
        0
    ],
    [
        1583636400000,
        0
    ],
    [
        1583640000000,
        0
    ],
    [
        1583643600000,
        0
    ],
    [
        1583647200000,
        0
    ]
]
```

El código de Highcharts es este:

```
<script>
Highcharts.getJSON(
    'JSON/graf_loggernet.json',
    //'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/usdeur.json',
    function (data) {
        var detailChart;

        // create the detail chart
        function createDetail(masterChart) {

            // prepare the detail chart
            var detailData = [],
                detailStart = data[0][0];

                //console.log(detailStart);

            $.each(masterChart.series[0].data, function () {
                if (this.x >= detailStart) {

                    //console.log(this.x);
                    detailData.push(this.y);
                }
            });

            //console.log(detailData);

            // create a detail chart referenced by a global variable
            detailChart = Highcharts.chart('detail-container', {
                chart: {
                    marginBottom: 120,
                    reflow: false,
                    marginLeft: 50,
                    marginRight: 20,
                    style: {
                        position: 'absolute'
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Historical USD to EUR Exchange Rate',
                    align: 'left'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Select an area by dragging across the lower chart',
                    align: 'left'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    maxZoom: 0.1
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        var point = this.points[0];
                        return '<b>' + point.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y %m %d %H %M', this.x) + ':<br/>' +
                            'Radiacion= ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y,9);
                    },
                    shared: true
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    radius: 3
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'USD to EUR',
                    pointStart: detailStart,
                    pointInterval: 1*3600*1000,
                    data: detailData
                }],

                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                }

            }); // return chart
        }

        // create the master chart
        function createMaster() {
            Highcharts.chart('master-container', {
                chart: {
                    reflow: false,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    backgroundColor: null,
                    marginLeft: 50,
                    marginRight: 20,
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    events: {

                        // listen to the selection event on the master chart to update the
                        // extremes of the detail chart
                        selection: function (event) {

                            var extremesObject = event.xAxis[0],
                                min = extremesObject.min,
                                max = extremesObject.max,
                                detailData = [],
                                xAxis = this.xAxis[0];

                             // reverse engineer the last part of the data
                            $.each(this.series[0].data, function () {
                                if (this.x > min && this.x < max) {
                                    detailData.push([this.x, this.y]);
                                }
                            });

                            // move the plot bands to reflect the new detail span
                            xAxis.removePlotBand('mask-before');
                            xAxis.addPlotBand({
                                id: 'mask-before',
                                from: data[0][0],
                                to: min,
                                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                            });

                            xAxis.removePlotBand('mask-after');
                            xAxis.addPlotBand({
                                id: 'mask-after',
                                from: max,
                                to: data[data.length - 1][0],
                                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                            });


                            detailChart.series[0].setData(detailData);

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                accessibility: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    showLastTickLabel: true,
                    maxZoom: 1 * 36000 * 1000, // fourteen days
                    plotBands: [{
                        id: 'mask-before',
                        from: data[0][0],
                        to: data[data.length - 1][0],
                        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                    }],
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    labels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    min: 0.6,
                    showFirstLabel: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        fillColor: {
                            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 70],
                            stops: [
                                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0)']
                            ]
                        },
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        shadow: false,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        },
                        enableMouseTracking: false
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    type: 'area',
                    name: 'USD to EUR',
                    pointInterval: 1 * 3600 * 1000,
                    pointStart: data[0][0],
                    data: data
                }],

                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                }

            }, function (masterChart) {
                createDetail(masterChart);
            }); // return chart instance
        }

        // make the container smaller and add a second container for the master chart
        var $container = $('#container')
            .css('position', 'relative');

        $('<div id="detail-container">')
            .appendTo($container);

        $('<div id="master-container">')
            .css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 300,
                height: 100,
                width: '100%'
            })
            .appendTo($container);

        // create master and in its callback, create the detail chart
        createMaster();
    }
);
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Chart showing how a second chart can be added to approach Highstock
        Navigator functionality in Highcharts. Click and drag in the lower
        chart to zoom in on the upper chart.
    </p>
</figure>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puedes probar cambiando el [timezone](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezone)

Comment: @granch lo voy a probar cuando amanezca xD muchas gracias espero sea eso, la verdad es que utilice anychart pero las gráficas de Highcharts están más chidas :V